# Соединить Два потока Два бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Хочу заставить работать два бота в двух поточном режиме

```
import  telebot
from threading import Thread

bot321 = telebot.TeleBot("59810")
bot123 = telebot.TeleBot("55073171")

@bot123.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot123.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Привет, я конструктор ботов в телеге, для того чтобы создать бота жми на кнопку')


@bot321.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send(message):
    bot321.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Привет, я конструктор ботов в телеге, для того чтобы создать бота жми на кнопку')

t1 = Thread(target=send_welcome, args=(1))
t2 = Thread(target=send,args=(1))
t1.start()
t2.start()
```